# Error in displaying an image in a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, imageview

I have an image resource ID in an SQLite database and I would like to display this image in a list view. I have created a row template but the default image is displayed in the list. How do I update the image src?

to populate the list view, I use the following code

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.winnerListView);

    int[] viewColumns = {R.id.winnerPositionView, R.id.winnerIcon, R.id.winnerNameView, R.id.winnerScoreView};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.result_row_layout, c, DatabaseHelper.PROJECTION, viewColumns, 0);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks

Comment: Displaying image in a list is a big topic in itself. Google has a nice tutorial about it. Here is the link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I would also like to update text in a textview also in the list, would it be a similar procedure?

Comment: Let me know that in the `viewColumns` array the values you have defined are the from the drawable folder ?

Comment: Grishu, yes, they are from the drawable folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ordes to do that you must have custom adapter class for list view ,using this adapter class you must set view for each row of listview

Here is some [Tutorial 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)  , [Tutorial 2](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429), [Tutorial 3](http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html), [Tutorial 4](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html) Hope this will help you

Comment: I ended up using a custom CursorAdapter. I followed a very simple example here [link](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/)

Comment: glad you solve your issue . Yeah Since you are using DB to fill list you must use CursorAdapter .I forget to quote that

Answer (score 0):

Here having sample projects how to load image in a list view. Please go through it.

[Click here for more details](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)