# How to search for column value in TableLayout?

Tags: android

How to search rows which are dynamically created in table layout of android? I'm having a table layout which contains name and code as columns, how do i search those rows for particular name/code?

I'm trying to add tag in this way:

```
TextView empFirstName = null; 
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<employees.size();i++){

    final Employee employee = (Employee) employees.get(i);

    int count = 0;

    TableRow empData = new TableRow(this);
    empData.setId(300+count);
    empData.setClickable(true);


    /*empData.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));*/
    //tr.setClickable(true);

    final TextView empCode = new TextView(this);
    empCode.setId(300+count);
    empCode.setText(employee.getCode());
    empCode.setTextSize(16);
    empCode.setPadding(2,2, 2, 2);
    empCode.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2 ));
    empData.addView(empCode);


    final TextView empName = new TextView(this);
    empName.setId(300+count);
    empName.setText(employee.getCallName());
    empName.setTextSize(16);
    empName.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    empName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4 ));
    empData.addView(empName);

    empFirstName = new TextView(this);
    empFirstName.setId(007);
    empFirstName.setText(employee.getFirstName());
    empFirstName.setTag(i);
}
```

I'm trying to use setTag(), how do i retrieve value of text using getTag()}

Comment: You might want to use `ListView` instead.

Comment: could you please explain in detail!!

Comment: are you trying to create a list showing employee details??

Comment: @edwin yes...but I'm showing them using TableLayout...

Comment: one more doubt :do you know about android list view widget ? which is used for creating list . Is there any particular reason for choosing table over  list-view?

Comment: @edwin I didn't knew about list view widget..I recently got into android development..

Comment: ok then list view is will help you to achieve your need

Comment: @edwin...Thanks for the suggestion!! I'm working on it :)

Answer (score 1):

so from your i comment i think you want to create a list which hold some details. Instead of going for TableView and rows .You can use list view

Go through this [Android developer site documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) .It will provide you many inbuilt features for getting row details and it's contents

Here is some tutorials :[Tutorial 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) and [Tutorial 3](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php)

These tutorial will help you to create simple list-view

First Get basic idea .Also get a picture about [Adapter view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

Later on you can customize the list view using custom adapter classes : [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14743456/1450401)

Hope this will help you

Comment: if you got stuck anywhere you can approach